# how to select a class using jquery a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a Bootstrap button:

### templatetag/q_extras.py

```
@register.filter(name='topic_following')
def is_user_following_topic(value,arg):
    try:
        tp=Topic.objects.get(id=int(value))
        usr=User.objects.get(id=int(arg))
        Followings.objects.get(user=usr,topic=tp)
        return 'btn-success'
    except:
        return 'btn-inverse'
```

### home.html

```
{% load q_extras %}
<button id="{{ topic.pk }}" 
class="follow btn {{ topic.pk|topic_following:user.pk }}" 
data-toggle="button">
Follow</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-success").text("UnFollow");
});
</script>
```

the above method is working fine but i know this is not the correct method since there may be button having the same class(.btn-success).

so i tried lot of other methods($(".follow").find(".btn-success"), even add a new class) ,but nothing is working. So i would like to know any other selectors for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can try `$(".follow .btn-success").text("UnFollow");` to be more specific.

u can also always use the id selector to be precise

`$("#id").text("UnFollow");`

Comment: sorry i tried already it is not working. that is why i am asking the question

Comment: then try `$('.btn-success').on('click',function(){$(this).text('unfollow')});`

Comment: no no i just want to sent it only when the page loads. not any other time

Comment: have you included the jquery library? because your code seems to be fine

Answer (score 1):

The best way to be sure you select only one element is using a selector by `id`. If you can do this then  your problem is solved since multiple html elements with same id is not allowed.

```
$("#btn-id").text("UnFollow"); // where btn-id is the id of the button
```

Comment: sorry the problem is there are a lots of buttons and each of them may either following(btn-success) or not following(btn-invers).

Comment: ok it is better to use the django templatetags or something that this messy jquery

Comment: actually i just want to set this button text when the page load. which i can either set in django templatetags or even in django view. so no need to try the jquery for this. i am using jquery for a lots of other things and it is beautiful.